# xUnit: pass fixture as type argument to another IClassFixture fixture

Tags: xunit, fixtures

I have base fixture and derived fixture.
And I try to put as a type parameter base fixture into another.
Is it legal as all?

Because I get this error:

> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Class
>   fixture type 'WebApplicationFixture' had one or more unresolved
>   constructor arguments: WebApplicationFactory`1 factory) (The following
>   constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data:
>   WebApplicationFixture fixture)
>   ---- Class fixture type 'WebApplicationFixture' had one or more unresolved constructor arguments: WebApplicationFactory`1 factory
>   ---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: WebApplicationFixture fixture
>
> ----- Inner Stack Trace #1 (Xunit.Sdk.TestClassException) -----
>
> ----- Inner Stack Trace #2 (Xunit.Sdk.TestClassException) -----

```
    public class WebApplicationFixture : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>, IDisposable
    {
        protected internal readonly string AbsoluteUri;
        protected internal readonly HttpClient HttpClient;
        protected internal readonly HttpMessageHandler HttpMessageHandler;

        public WebApplicationFixture(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            HttpClient = factory.CreateClient();
            HttpMessageHandler = factory.Server.CreateHandler();
            AbsoluteUri = factory.Server.BaseAddress.AbsoluteUri;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            HttpClient?.Dispose();
            HttpMessageHandler?.Dispose();
        }
    }

public class BasicTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFixture>, IDisposable
{
    public BasicTests(WebApplicationFixture fixture)
    {
        _fixture = fixture;
        _clientBuilder = _fixture.ClientBuilder;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _fixture.Dispose();
    }

    private readonly WebApplicationFixture _fixture;

}
```

Comment: The Fixture has to have a parameterless constructor: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/112